# CoreText Horizontal Center Alignment of Text

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-text

I'm using `CoreText` and I want to make it so my `NSMutableAttributedString` always center aligns its text. This is the code I'm using and it isn't working:

```
CTTextAlignment paragraphAlignment = kCTCenterTextAlignment;
    CTParagraphStyleSetting paragraphSettings[1] = {{kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &paragraphAlignment}};
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(paragraphSettings, 1);

text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"" attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: (id)paragraphStyle, (NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil]];
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this correctly?

Comment: What is the rest of your code for displaying the text?  (The answer depends on the routines that you are using).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801856/iphone-nsattributedstring-add-text-alignment/6801901#6801901 should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution without to use CoreText if your app is compatible with 10.10 or upper, it is to use NSParagraphStyle.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *rectStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
rectStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
rectStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSMutableAttributedString *att = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myText attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : rectStyle}];
```