# Attributed Text Center Alignment

Tags: ios, xcode, label, nsattributedstring, centering

I have tried everything but cannot seem to center this text. Can someone please tell me where the error is.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cell.EventTitle.text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @0,NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"BrandonGrotesque-Black" size:34]}];
```

Comment: check out this link....it may help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801856/iphone-nsattributedstring-add-text-alignment

Answer (score 168):

**In Swift 5**

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "String",
                                                     attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraph])
```

**In Swift-4**

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center

let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraph]
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string:"string", attributes: attributes)
textView.attributedText =  attrString
```

**In Swift-3**

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center

let attributes: [String : Any] = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph]
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string:"string", attributes: attributes)
textView.attributedText =  attrString
```

Comment: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName - > NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle

Answer (score 64):

You can set the center alignment using this. Remember to set range.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Answer (score 40):

**In Swift 4**

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center

textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "string",
                                         attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraph])
```

Answer (score 28):

Another way:

**Swift**:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "This will be centered.", attributes: [ NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
```

**Obj-C**:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;    
NSAttributedString *attributedString =  [NSAttributedString.alloc initWithString:@"This will be centered." 
attributes: @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}];
```

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 4+**

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

// Swift 4.2++
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle])

// Swift 4.1--
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle])

let yourLabel = UILabel()
yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *string = @"Your String";
NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes: @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: You forgot to add the attribute to the string in the ObjC example :)

Answer (score 16):

In Swift

```
let titleString = "title here"

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(
    string: titleString,
    attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
)

titleAttributedLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 11):

helper method based on the helpful answers above

```
public extension NSAttributedString
{
    var centered: NSAttributedString
    {
        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.alignment = .center
        let m = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        m.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraph, range: NSMakeRange(0, length))
        return m
    }
}
```

in case you want the Is dotted and Ts crossed el verbositas version

```
var centered: NSAttributedString {
        let paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle],
                                       range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        return attributedString
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift4**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Example text that is centered using a paragraph style. With the ability to change the width between lines.", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: GothamFont.medium(with: 14)])

let myParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
myParagraphStyle.alignment = .center // center the text
myParagraphStyle.lineSpacing = 14 //Change spacing between lines
myParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 38 //Change space between paragraphs
attributedString.addAttributes([.paragraphStyle: myParagraphStyle], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

To do it in Swift 2.x

```
let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "text")
style.alignment = .Center
attributeString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: range)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when text is in Arabic or other right align languages then when doing alignment Justified, last line text ends at left side. for this we can add **baseWritingDirection** below is sample code

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .rightToLeft
attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:range)
txtView.attributedText = attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

Set line breakmode, if you set attributed text on UIButton.

**Swift 5**

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center
paragraph.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

Answer (score -2):

This works for me
label.textAlignment = .center