# NSAttributedString combination of 2 Strings with new line

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to achieve this kind of date
[image: Date]

inside a collection view cell.
So i have the day's number and the month on 2 separate strings.

```
var day = example.date
var month = example.month
```

and with the functions below I'm changing them font color etc.

```
 func formatMonth(fullString: String, fontSize: Double) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let range = (fullString as NSString).range(of: fullString)

    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString)

    myMutableString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: CGFloat(fontSize))!
        , NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red], range: range)


    return myMutableString
}
func formatDay(fullString: String, fontSize: Double) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let range = (fullString as NSString).range(of: fullString)

    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString)

    myMutableString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(fontSize))!
        , NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black], range: range)


    return myMutableString
}
```

And the variables are becoming like this

```
let theMonth = formatMonth(fullString: example.month, fontSize: 15)
let theDay = formatDay(fullString: example.date, fontSize: 13)
```

Then i combine them

```
let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()
        combination.append(theDay)
        combination.append(theMonth)
```

and finally i get the combination of the text.

```
date.attributedText = combination
```

So by this approach i can see the one next to the other `8FEb`

how can i add a breaking line between them?

Comment: As a sidenote, there is no point to set `myMutableString` and then set it again in the next line... so it can become `var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString)` in one go

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add `\n` with day.

```
let theDay = formatDay(fullString: "\(example.date)\n", fontSize: 13)
```

You need to set `NSMutableParagraphStyle` to make your text `center`. Try like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37579180/6433023) for that, you need to make little bit changes to make it working with Swift 3 and make sure you have sufficient `height` to show 2 lines.

Comment: If you are using attributedstring then textAlignment doesn't work.

Comment: @RahulPatel Edited answer for that.

Comment: You can also just add the separator when combining the results `combination.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))`.